# How to set permission anyone for API Drive v3

Tags: php, curl, google-drive-api

So the story is like this, I have a Google Drive file sharing web, now when I use it, the file that is copied by the application is still private, how do I change the permissions so that it becomes anyone / public?

The script below does not work to set file copy permissions to anyone.

This is the code fuction that I used:

```php
function insertPermission($id, $token) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/$id/permissions?key=$token");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer $token", "{\"role\":\"reader\",\"type\":\"anyone\"}"));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{\"role\":\"reader\",\"type\":\"anyone\"}");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
}

function copyfile($id, $token) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/$id/copy?access_token=$token");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-length: 0", "Content-type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer $token"));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return json_decode($result, true);
}
```

Here is the calling code:

```php
$ruse = token("refresh", $_SESSION[email]);
$copy = copyfile($share[file][file_id], $ruse[access_token]);
insertPermission($copy[id], $ruse[access_token]);

if ($copy[id]) {

    echo " <
        meta http - equiv = \"refresh\" content=\"10;URL='https://docs.google.com/uc?id=$copy[id]'\" /> <
        div class = \"my-3 p-3 bg-white rounded shadow\"> <
        div style = \"padding: 50px 15px;text-align: center;background-color: #fff;\"> <
        h3 > Start Download < /h3><br / >
        Click < a href = \"https://docs.google.com/uc?id=$copy[id]\" target=\"_blank\">here</a> for download. <
        /div> <
        /div>";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer:

*You can use the `Permissions: create`<sup>[[1]](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create)</sup> method of the Google Drive API to create a new Permission with the parameters you require.*

#### More Information:

Making a `Permissions: create` request to the Drive API with the ID of the file you wish to set the permission on will set up the permission. After obtaining the file ID of the file that has been newly created by your application, you can make the request along with a request body which contains the permission type.

#### Example cURL Request:

```
curl --request POST \
  'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/<YOUR-FILE-ID-GOES-HERE>/permissions?key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{"role":"reader","type":"anyone"}' \
  --compressed
```

The `data '{"role":"reader","type":"anyone"}'` line sets the permissions such that anyone with the link can view the file, but not edit. You can read more about the Permissions resource<sup>[[2]](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions#resource)</sup> in the Drive API documentation, which goes into the allowed values of `type` and `role`.

#### References:

1. [Google Drive API - `Permissions: create`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create)
2. [Google Drive API - `Permissions` resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions#resource)

Comment: I have added the Permissions: create function as I wrote it in my question above.

But Google Drive files that have been copied still have private permission, not anyone.

How to make the correct Permissions: create function.